# wpf crystalreport viewer dissappear for no reason

Tags: wpf, vb.net, crystal-reports

Well the problem is easy to explain and hard to figure out, at least by me, so i have a tabcontrol with 3 tabitem, on one of the tabitems i have a wpf reportviewer that loads a report of some data, when i change tabs, it does not matter to each one when i get back to the tab with the crystalreport in it, the crystalreport viewer is not there anytmore! i also have a button on top to refresh the report and the button is still there but the crystal report control is not there anymore!

my xaml looks like this

```
<UserControl x:Class="uccvrFactuur"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Report" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" />
        <my:CrystalReportsViewer Name="crvFactuur" Margin="0,60,0,0" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

i must say the first time i click on that tab the control is there but i change tabs and go back to it the control is not there anymore.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I am having the exact same problem! Did you manage to find a solution or workaround for this problem? Thanx

Comment: Hey Chrisjan Lodewyks, no i havent found a solution yet for this problem, i do have a work around, a nasty one, each time the user change tabs i would re-create the crystal report control once again, the bad part about this is all the data would be lost and the user is forced to put the values again(in my case a date from a a date to).. Like i said not the best solution but until i find a better one i will have to use this methode.